# Foreign key based on multiple row ids

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to figure out how to store a combination of id fields as a foreign key in another table. For example, say TableA has 5 rows -- Ids 1-5.

Without using a comma separated field is there a way I can make rows in TableB based off different combinations of TableA's ids? For example rows[1,3], rows[2,3], rows[1], rows[2,3,4] -- the thing throwing me off is it will always be a variable number of row ids that I am putting together.

Is a comma separated field the only way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help or pointers...

Answer (score 5):

You're describing a many-to-many relationship between TableA and TableB. You should introduce a third table to resolve this. This new table consists of two foreign keys, one referencing the ID from TableA and one from TableB.

[image]

Comment: Good answer, just for example, the third table will have rows like `[1,1], [3,1], [2,2], [3,2], [1,3], [2,4], [3,4] [4,4]`, with A's key first.